# verifyIdToken() method of firebase-admin sdk keeps awaiting without being resolved

Tags: flutter, nestjs, firebase-admin

I have a Flutter application that uses,

- firebase_auth: 3.3.20
- firebase_core: 1.24.0
- google_sign_in: 5.4.3
- firebase_messaging: 11.4.4

On my NestJS backend, I use,

- firebase-admin": "^10.0.1".

I get the id token using `FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.getIdToken();` from flutter side, and send this to my NestJS backend. I have made sure the full token is received to the `token` variable without issue.

When I run `await verifyIdToken(token)`, the method is never resolved. On my API client (Insomnia), the request keeps loading untill I quit the request. However, if I send a random string (not JWT) as the `token`, the the expected rejection is obtained fromt he `verifyIdToken` method.

My questions,

1. Has something been changed in the firebase-admin sdk recently that could affect this?
2. Could this be a bug on firebase side? (I highly doubt it but my code worked a lot earlier (about 1 year ago)).

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I was fiddling around this for a while but just after I posted the question, it occured to me I should do some,

- `npm cache verify`
- Delete `node_modules` folder
- Run `npm install`

Strangely enough, now the method `verifyIdToken()` works. I don't know how it happened, but now it works. Strange.

Explanations are still welcome!